# Determining the two largest numbers from user input

Tags: python

I've been working on a small program to learn more about Python, but I'm stuck on something.

Basically, the user has to input a sequence of positive integers. When a negative number is entered, the program stops and tells the user the two largest integers the user previously inputted. Here is my code:

```py
number = 1
print("Please enter your desired integers. Input a negative number to end. ")

numbers = []

while (number > 0):
   number = int(input())
   if number < 0:
      break
  
largestInteger = max(numbers)
print(largestInteger)

integers.remove(largestInteger)
largestInteger2 = max(numbers)
print(largestInteger2)
```

Comment: What happens if the user enters 0?

Comment: Inside the input loop, you aren't _doing anything_ with the input.  Presumably you intended to add it to the `numbers` list?

Comment: I've rolled back the previous edit as it removed the original (flawed) code. As a gentle reminder, SO questions help future readers. I'm glad your issue is resolved, but edits that remove the original code prevent readers from understanding the context in which an answer was given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. You need to update the list with the user input for every iteration of the `while` loop using `.append()`.
2. `integers` isn't defined, so you can't call `.remove()` on it. You should refer to `numbers` instead.

Here is a code snippet that resolves these issues:

```py
number = 1
print("Please enter your desired integers. Input a negative number to end. ")

numbers = []

while number > 0:
   number = int(input())
   if number > 0:
       numbers.append(number)
  
largestInteger = max(numbers)
print(largestInteger)

numbers.remove(largestInteger)
largestInteger2 = max(numbers)
print(largestInteger2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helped me. I also added the 0 to the integers list so whenever the user inputs a 0, it will be counted as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

I would build a function that would call itself again if the user enters a number larger or equal to 0, but will break itself and return a list once a user inputs a number smaller than 0. Additionally I would then sort in reverse (largest to smallest) and call only the first 2 items in the list

```
def user_input():
    user_int = int(input('Please enter your desired integers'))
    if user_int >= 0:
        user_lst.append(user_int)
        user_input()
    else:
        return user_lst

#Create an empty list
user_lst = []
user_input()
user_lst.sort(reverse=True)
user_lst[0:2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to append the input **number** to the **numbers** list

````
numbers = []

while (True):
    number = int(input())
    if number < 0:
        break
    numbers.append(number)

print("First largest integer: ", end="")
largestInteger = max(numbers)
print(largestInteger)

numbers.remove(largestInteger)
print("Second largest integer: ", end="")
largestInteger2 = max(numbers)
print(largestInteger2)```

The above code will work, according to your **desire**
````